# Программа на С неправильно вычисляет значение ряда Тейлора для больших n

Tags: c, ряды, численные-методы, overflow

Программа должна вычислять значение формулы ниже с точностью до n-ного члена и с максимальной точностью, то есть то бесконечности (наступает момент, когда дальше считать сумму бессмысленно, именно поэтому можем посчитать до бесконечности). [image] Вот мой код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

long double powl(long double x, unsigned long y) {
    long double res = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
        res *= x;
    }
    return res;
}

long double move(long double x, unsigned int n) {
    long double res = 1;
    while (n > 0) {
        res *= x / n;
        n -= 1;
    }
    return res;
}

void teylor_na(long double x, unsigned int n) {
    long double sum = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= n; i += 1) {
        sum += (powl(-1, i + 1)) * (move(x, i));
    }
    printf("non-accurate result is %Le\n", sum);
}

void teylor_a(long double x) {
    int critical = 0;
    long double sum = 0;
    double p_inf = powl(10, 100000);
    double n_inf = -powl(10, 100000);
    for (unsigned int i = 1; ((sum + ((powl(-1, i + 1)) * (move(x, i))) != p_inf) &&
        (sum + ((powl(-1, i + 1)) * (move(x, i))) != n_inf) &&
        (sum + ((powl(-1, i + 1)) * (move(x, i))) != sum)); i += 1) {
        sum += (powl(-1, i + 1)) * (move(x, i));
        critical = i;
    }
    printf("accurate result is %Le\n", sum);
    printf("you will get the same with non-accurate function if n = %d", critical);
}

void main() {
    long double x;
    unsigned int n;
    printf("Enter x: ");
    scanf("%Le", &x);
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%lu", &n);
    teylor_na(x, n);
    teylor_a(x);
}
```

При малых n функция хорошо считает ответ до n-го члена. Начиная примерно со 160 начинаются расхождения. Дан тест x = 88 n = 1000. Программу нужно исправить так, чтобы она правильно проходила его. Как вы видите, n довольно большое. Сначала программа вычисляла отдельно -1 в степени, x в степени и факториал n, но происходило переполнение. Поэтому пришлось вычислять (x^n)/(n!) отдельно в функции move. Но здесь появилось много деления, которое, как я предполагаю, дает большую погрешность и программа дает неправильный результат! Но как его убрать, я не знаю. Для большего понимания, вот что программа выдает, если каждую итерацию цикла teylor_na выводить сумму, то, что будет к ней прибавлено и номер итерации: [image] [image] [image]

То есть, в конкретный момент суммы почему-то перестают чередоваться по знаку, а потом сумма и вовсе застывает на определенном значении. Почему так происходит я понять не смог

Comment: Так происходит потому что *n!* растёт намного быстрее чем *x^n*. в этом нет ничего удивительного.

Comment: Попробуйте считать слагаемые в ряду парами. Это позволит избежать вычитания огромных близких по модулю но разных по знаку величин.

Comment: а как именно считать парами? то есть у нас есть сумма x/1! - x^2/2! + x^3/3! - x^4/4! + ... и так далее, и нужно по два слагаемых приводить к общему знаменателю и считать как одно? или я неправильно понял

Comment: Вы правильно поняли. Это несколько поднимет точность. Правда, вам нужно поднимать точность очень сильно. Если вы угадаете что это за ряд, вы сможете делать над ним алгебраические операции, с помощью которых точность можно будет улучшить очень сильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут весь вопрос, вам нужны шашечки или вам надо ехать?

Дело в том, что этот ряд — это `1-exp(-x)`, так что для 88 вы получите `1-6e-39`, и никакая точность `double` вам такой ответ просто не выдаст. Для точности где-то в 18 разрядов, которую обеспечивает `double`, вы можете считать до 40 и не более.

Так что если нужны "шашечки", т.е. просто сдать работу — рисуете код типа

```
double bruteForce(double x, unsigned int n)
{
    double term = x, sum = x;
    for(unsigned int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        sum += term *= -x/i;
    return sum;
}
```

который считает ваш ряд (т.е. показываете свое умение преподу) и поясняете, почему для заданных им значений получится ерунда — из-за роста членов до примерно `n = x`, который "забьет" всю точность и того, что результат просто равен 1.

Если преподу надо какие-то другое шашечки, то ему надо точно пояснить, что он от вас хочет.

Если препод умный и хочет ехать, т.е. конкретный результат, то, как я же говорил, для таких чисел он в `double` не влезет, т.е. все, что вы можете — это дать результат в виде "1-ε, где ε = ....".

Как посчитать этот ε? С конца. Т.е. считать не сумму этих первых 1000 чисел, а начиная с 1001 и далее, пока точность не станет достаточной — для оценки этого хвоста ε. Зная точный результат суммы бесконечного ряда.

Но что-то "терзают меня смутные сомнения" (с), что это выходит за рамки обычной лабы для начинающих.

Других вариантов не вижу. Даже если собирать соседние члены в пары — все равно это не даст достаточного уменьшения членов для работы с указанными аргументами.

Впрочем, может, вы эти 88 и 1000 не из задания взяли, а сами "из головы придумали"? тогда просто не берите такие совершенно непригодные для численных расчетов через ряды значения. Универсальных методов ("серебряной пули") не существует...

Comment: спасибо за ответ! у меня остался еще один вопрос. когда я пытаюсь проверить через вольфрам альфа работу программы (именно когда суммируем до бесконечности, а не до n), то ответ всегда такой: -1/e^x. может вам известно, откуда взята эта формула? если я это пойму, то смогу при больших n вычислять просто математически по этой формуле. кстати тот пример я придумал не из головы, это действительно тест препода

Comment: Ну сами смотрите — из ряда для e^x=1+x+x^2/2+x^3/6+... легко получить e^(-x) = 1/e^x =1-x+x^2/2-x^3/6+... = 1 - (x-x^2/2+x^3/6-...) — но в скобках и есть искомый ряд. Т.е. он равен, перенося его влево, а  1/e^x вправо, 1 - e^(-x). Так все понятно?

Comment: да, спасибо большое